# Mischaracterization of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof 4.2.5 in *A Course in Linear Algebra* fixes $k$ sets of $n_i$ eigenvectors to prove the linear independence of $s = \{x_{1,1}\ldots, x_{1,n_1}\} \cup \ldots \cup \{x_{k,1},\ldots,x_{k,n_k}\}.$

However it's stated later for each $1 \leq i \leq k$ the sum $a_{i,1}x{i,1}+\ldots+a_{i,n_i}x_{i,n_i}$ is an element of the eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i}.$

Earlier $E_\lambda$ is defined as the union of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and 0.

Is this not two different definitions of $E_\lambda$? One is a linear combination of eigenvectors and the other is a union.

The textbook uses dim($E_\lambda$), which leads me to think it is a linear combination and the given definition is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The first reference you cite is not a definition. It just states that if $x_{i,1}, x_{i,2}, \dots, x_{i,n_i}$ are eigenvectors, so is $a_{i,1} x_{i,1} + a_{i,2} x_{i,2} + \dots + a_{i,n_i} x_{i,n_i}$ for any scalars $\{a_{i,j} \}$. You can test this by applying the linear transformation that these are eigenvectors of

The second reference, that is the definition: $E_\lambda$ is the set of all eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and also the zero vector. We have to throw in the zero vector because it's not counted as an eigenvector.

Comment: I see. $$T(a_{i,1}x_{i,1} +  a_{i,2}x_{i,1}  + \ldots + a_{i,n_j}x_{i,n_j}) = T(a_{i,1}x_{i,1}) + T( a_{i,2}x_{i,1}) + \ldots + T(a_{i,n_j}x_{i,n_j}) = \lambda((a_{i,1}x_{i,1} +  a_{i,2}x_{i,1}  + \ldots + a_{i,n_j}x_{i,n_j})$$ Thus $$a_{i,1}x_{i,1} +  a_{i,2}x_{i,1}  + \ldots + a_{i,n_j}x_{i,n_j} \in E_\lambda$$ Thanks for the help.